# Detect SFSafariViewController within javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, sfsafariviewcontroller

How could I detect from `UI/javascript` side that my web application was loaded not in the Safari but in the in-app browser (for example like in-app browser of gmail's iOS application) with a help of `SFSafariViewController`? We checked a lot of properties of `document` and `window` like `navigator` and `userAgent` and seems like all of them are identical in both browsers